# GeoDjango vary geometry type in model/serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, geodjango

I try to make some raster statistics based on Django and [rasterstats](https://github.com/perrygeo/python-rasterstats) lib. User requests GeoJson and in the response, I should also provide GeoJson. Geometry should be stored in the database model.

For now, I have things working using `models.PolygonField`, but I would like to add to that other geometry types.

I am using django-rest-framework-gis

models.py

```
class CalculateLocation(Base):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    otherProperties = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    geometry = models.PolygonField(blank=True)
    min = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=20)
    max = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=20)
    mean = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=20)
```

serializers.py

```
class CalculateLocationSerializer(GeoFeatureModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = CalculateLocation
        geo_field = "geometry"
        fields = (
            'id',
            'otherProperties',
            'min',
            'max',
            'mean'
        )
```

How can I store and serialize/deserialize vary geometry type in one field, for example, Point, Polygon, Multipolygon etc.?

EDIT:

I managed set generic geometry in the model using `GeometryField` - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/#geometryfield

Using this kind of field I can insert every geometry type using WKT, WKB, GeoJson format with `GEOSGeometry` - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#creating-a-geometry